# "in which" and "during which"

Tags: grammar

Is "**in which**" interchangeable with "**during which**"? I've seen them replaced with each other in videos and articles. But no books explain the question.

Comment: If the referent is a ***time period*** (or something which can be creatively *interpreted* as such), you can use either preposition, but you can only use ***in*** in all other contexts (physical / logical "containment" of one thing ***within*** another).

Comment: As Wilson answered, I think using "**in which**" and "**during which**" in the same time period context will not mean the same.

Comment: Without bothering to think it through (or reader that answer fully and carefully), I wouldn't be surprised if there are contexts where (nearly?) everyone would agree that the choice between ***in which*** and ***during which*** could affect meaning. But with, for example, *I'm talking about the month **in / during** which the referendum was held*, there is no possible distinction - ***and*** I would take issue with anyone who claimed that either version should be "preferred" in that specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always.

**in** often means within some kind of boundary, but **during** means within some time frame.

For example "the jar in which I hid your money", or "the country or region in which he spent his childhood". These phrases cannot work with "during which".

As for things which take time, like meetings or weeks, there is sometimes a difference:

- "the week during which I was sick" could mean I was sick for seven days
- "the week in which I was sick" could be, I was sick for maybe one day, but I am talking about the whole week surrounding that illness.

But for telic actions (that is, things which happen at once and don't take a long time) that happen inside of a length of time, "in" and "during" can often both work:

- The business meeting in which he embarrassed himself *or the business meeting during which ...*
- The holiday during which I met her *or the holiday on which ...*

Then there are phrases where you simply need to learn which is the fitting preposition. Usually in that case it will be *in*. For example:

- I did it in a grand/selfish/loving manner. *The manner in which I did it was ...*
- I looked the monster directly in his third eye. *The eye in which I looked him ...*

Comment: I think that last example was a bit silly, I'm sure you can think of a better example

Comment: Is it possible that they are interchangeable in some other contexts?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple yep, I just explained.

Comment: Your examples are in descending order of weirdness. That's because a week really is not a location, but a meeting kind of is, and a jar certainly is.

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple also, "in which" is not always interchangeable with "where"; consider "the street corner where he was mugged"

Comment: So it is totally incorrect to say "the week where I was sick"?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple Not totally wrong. It just seems a little strange (to me! maybe another English speaker will have a different opinion). I think "The week **when** I was sick" seems better because a week is a time period

Comment: How about "The business meeting where he embarrassed himself"? Does it sound a little strange too?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple It's okay. Not as weird as "the week where...".

Comment: How about "The eye where I looked him ..."? How do you feel about this one?

Comment: Not good I have to say. That's because it's a set phrase, "to look [someone] in the eye". So you do actually need the "in".

Comment: But "the country or region where he spent his childhood" totally works, right?

Comment: Absolutely. There's nothing wrong with that

Comment: I get it. Now, how about "The holiday where I met her" or "The holiday when I met her", which one sounds better?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple, Maybe it depends on the kind of holiday: "The holiday when I met her" could be if I spent some Christmas at home or whatever, but "the holiday where I met her", would rather be if travelled somewhere and met someone there.

Comment: In this case, does "The holiday when I met her" mean the same as "The holiday during which I met her"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88583/discussion-between-wilson-and-relative-clauses-vs-participle).

Comment: Hello, please come back. I have replied to you!